# What is the best way to solder a breakout board to a PCB or Protoboard

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I am putting together a small project and I am thinking about how I am going to get it to the PCB stage. I am currently making use of a few breakout boards because they are easy to get and they seem to do a good job.

In the case of the TP4056 module would it be ok to just use the whole thing and mount it on my PCB rather than having to replicate the whole circuit on my PCB?
[image]
If that is ok then what would be the best way to solder it to the PCB so that it takes up as little space as possible. I don't really want to put header pins on it as this will make it stick up from the board a bit too much.

thanks
SOS

Comment: Header pins is probably the only option unless you want to glue it and use wires?

Comment: If it's a single-sided board, you could place it directly on top of some pads and fill the pin holes with solder, perhaps? I've seen that done (usually with cut-through holes) before.

Answer (score 2):

Router the corner off your board and leave generous pads to match the ones on the small PCB.  Drop robust wire links into the matching holes and solder.  All you loose is the real estate but your board remains the same height.